# Access website in and RDP using it's IP address

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2, rdp

I have an `RDP` located in the UK, and I have `Windows Server R2` installed in it, and I'm developing a website using ASP.Net.

I have `IIS` installed on that `RDP`, And I want people to access to my website via their navigators using the `RDP's Address`.

Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If this RDP/IIS box has public/real IP exposed directly to the internet you should not have poblems with it. Just go to site bindings in IIS and configure it appropriately (default binding imply listening on port 80 on all IP requests). Additional firewall configuration may be required to allow incoming trafic from WAN to your box on respective port.

Though it's quite unlikely that your RDP/IIS box directly exposed to the Internet (usually such things placed behind firewall or something similar)... In this case extra configuration steps may be required.